# How to disable click on touch pad?

Tags: windows-7, touchpad, mouse-click, hp-elitebook

I have a laptop with a touch pad running Windows 7 for HP EliteBook 8730w.  I find it really annoying that it takes clicks from the touch pad surface.

How can I disable clicks originating from the touch pad surface?  I only want the surface to control mouse position and to use the explicit buttons for clicks.

Comment: that is driver dependent, we need to know exactly what laptop you have...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For laptops in general:

> Go to **Control Panel**, then **Mouse**, then click the **Device Settings** tab and you should see your touch pad as one of the devices. Make sure your touch pad is highlighted and click the **Settings** button and you will see **Tapping** as one of the choices.

From: http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic52389.html

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a Synaptics touchpad, right-click on the touchpad icon in the notification area (system tray) and uncheck **Tap to Click**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the device settings, you can leave the touchstyk enabled, but disable its buttons.  that only disables the upper touchpad buttons.  you can disable the touchstyk as well.  But, if you re enable it, it will automatically re enable the top buttons again.  Interestingly, if you disable the touchstyk buttons, the tap-to-clik on the touchstyk is also disabled, meaning you can only point with the touchstyk.  The touchpad with its lower buttons are equally available for independent enable/disable.  Signed, equally annoyed by the top touchpad and touchstyck click actions while typing rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider to install [TouchFreeze](http://touchfreeze.googlecode.com): Small utility that blocks touchpad while you are typing.

> Annoyed when you are typing a document and accidentally the palm of
>   your hand brushes the touchpad, changing the position of the cursor in
>   your document or accidentally clicking on an option. TouchFreeze is
>   simple utility for Windows to solve this problem. It automatically
>   disables touchpad while you are typing text.

Answer (score 1):

### ***MOUSE Clicks TO MY ACTIVE WINDOW*** (Stops working sporadically)

Here is what I tried on my Linux Mint 18 [Mate] / Samsung RV510 laptop

[Based on the idea of disabling the suspected faulty Touchpad ]

[this gets a list of the input hardware installed]

smarts@Sams ~ $ **`xinput list`**

> ⎡ Virtual core pointer                  id =2 [master pointer  (3)] ⎜ 
>   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer        id=4  [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳
>   Microsoft  Microsoft  Mouse       id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳
>   ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad          id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎣
>   Virtual core keyboard                 id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
>       ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard       id=5  [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Power Button                      id=6  [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Video Bus                         id=7  [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Power Button                      id=8  [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Sleep Button                      id=9  [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ WebCam SCB-0355N                  id=10 [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳   USB Keyboard                    id=12 [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳   USB Keyboard                    id=13 [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard      id=14 [slave  keyboard (3)]

**[Trying to disable the touchpad]**

smarts@Sams ~ $ **`input set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" = 0`**

> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range
>   for operation)   Major opcode of failed request:  131
>   (XInputExtension)   Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()   Value in
>   failed request:  0x88   Serial number of failed request:  20   Current
>   serial number in output stream:  21

{It seems I will not be able to disable the touch pad this way!!!!}

**Soln**

**[Linux Mint 18 [Mate] :  Menu]  /  [Control centre] 
 /  [Hardware :mouse]  /  [Touch-pad] /**

**☐ Enable touch-pad    (removed tick)**

{ This effectively blocked the faulty touch pad's [spurious mouse movements] &  [stealing control of main mouse click}

Great this worked!!!

## ON WIN7

Try **disabling it on your windows OS**
Image result for disabling touchpad on windows
The Mouse Properties window will open; you might find a tab in that window where you can disable the touchpad.

```
Look for a touchpad software entry in the Start menu if you can't find it in the notification area or under Mouse Properties.
Click Start.
Expand Mice and other pointing devices.
```

More items...
How to Disable Your Laptop Touchpad | PCWorld
www.pcworld.com/article/241048/how_to_disable_your_laptop_touchpad.html

Comment: No! I rarely Joke. The sporadic input is the cause of the problem! Disabling the keypad or replacing it solves the problem. Replacing / Disabling is not OS specific!

Comment: Mint [Mate] combo is a very good replacement for the obsoleted Microsoft's Vista 32/64 OS.  Since this year we now have full flash capabilities in Linux

Comment: Fair enough I added a win7 ending to do the question justice / and point the user in the right direction.

Comment: The user's problem exists on many OS's not only WIN. The root cause is the faulty machinery!

Comment: OP had already his answer and only disable click on touch pad is wanted

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, HP EliteBook has default settings which make it virtually impossible to use the trackpad without accidentally clicking all the time. Fortunately, changing the settings will make the situation much better:

1. In Windows, go to Control Panel
2. Mouse
3. Device Settings tab
4. Select Synaptics LuxPad and click Settings
5. Deselect Tapping